# Update user on link click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to update `issue.assignee` field after clicking on link in `issues/show` view. Assign current_user to this field. How to do it?

I have to make link like this?

```
= link_to project_issue_path(issue.project, issue), method: :put
```

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MVC**

You need to appreciate that Rails is built on the [MVC (Model View Controller)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) programming pattern:

[image]

The reason I mention this is because when you create a piece of functionality in Rails (typically known as an `action`), you'll have to create the correct `controller#action` to help it work correctly:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :projects do
  resources :issues do
    put :assign #-> domain.com/projects/:project_id/issues/:id/assign
  end
end
```

This will allow you to create the corresponding `controller` action to handle the update:

```
#app/controllers/issues_controller.rb
Class IssuesController < ApplicationController
   def assign
      @issue = Issue.find parmas[:id]
      @issue.assignee = current_user.id
   end
end
```

This means you'll be able to send a simple `PUT` request (no form required) to this action as follows:

```
#app/views/issues/show.html.erb
<%= link_to "Update Assign", project_issue_path(issue.project, issue), method: :put %>
```

--

**Programming**

The question you're asking is basically *"how do I make it so my link actually *does* something"*

The answer is rather simple - you just need to make sure you have the *backend* functionality in place to handle the requests you want to send. As the MVC principle decrees - your "view" is actually rendered *last* - your *controller* is loaded first

Each time you send a request through a *route* to Rails, you basically get the middleware "routing" your request to a specific `controller#action`. The controller then takes the `params` extracted from the middleware, applies them to the functionality defined in your action, which can then be passed to your `Model`.

Lastly, the controller renders the corresponding `view` for your request - allowing you to *see* the updated data on screen!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a standard form for that, assuming assignee is a column in your issues table.

Use a hidden field, pre-populated with current_user. Upon submitting the form you would be  saving that current_user to your issue.assignee column.

i.e

```
<%= form_for @issue do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :assignee, :value => "#{current_user.id}" %>
<%= f.submit "Assign Current User %>
<% end %>
```

edit - you can then add this to any of your views